# Push notification certificate error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using push notification in my app.

But whenever i try to build the following error is showing.

Can anyone help me with this.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not of Beacause Push Notification..... Follow these Easy Steps for submitting Apps... If also u r not Clear tell me i will Help you directly :))

This is the [Link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store-a-step-by-step-guide/)... Hope this Helps.. :))

And If you dont Want to Submit apps then Just Go to Build info of ur Project and select "Don't Code Sign" in **Code Signing** Tab.

Comment: If it helps... you can say "thank you" by Upvoting the answer. I m glad that it helps your Problem. :))

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you have selected the wrong certificate or your token for push notifications has expired . Follow this guide http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/